# Test Report splitting for specific testcase groups belonging to the same test node

Tags: capl, canoe

Is it possible to execute all the testcases of a test node in CANoe and have more reports instead of a single html report with the whole result?

I would get one report for each testgroup in the same node.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

In the configuration dialog of your test modules, test configurations and test units, you can select an XSLT stylesheet which is used to generate the HTML report out of the XML result file.

There are already several XSLT sheets that create multipage output. If that does not fit your use case exactly, you can write your own stylesheet.

Comment: Thank you! I tried the other XSLT stylesheets but no one match with my need.
Unfortunately I am not so experienced with XSLT editing.
Is there a easy way to have one HTML for each test group of my node?

**1 HTML for each Testgroupbegin/Testgroupend, not 1 page for each, I would have different HTML files

Comment: As said, you have to create an XSLT Stylesheet that creates the output you need. That is the easiest way.